# Open .pdf, .docx, .xlsx, etc with default device application in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to open .pdf, .docx, .xlsx and other similar files using React Native.

I am currently downloading the files from an amazon s3 bucket to the device, then attempting to open them on the device using [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) `android.actionViewIntent(res.path(), mimeType)`.

This works fine with images, but with anything else I'm getting the following error:

`Error: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myappname/files/1475.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x10000000 }`

EDIT: For anyone here who would like to see the implementation that ended up working (using react-native-file-system and react-native-fetch-blob):

```
const fileType = fileDownloadPath.split('.').pop();
const SavePath = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath : RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath;
const mimeType = getMimeType(fileType); // getMimeType is a method (switch statement) that returns the correct mimetype
const path = `${SavePath}/${filename}.${fileType}`;
const android = RNFetchBlob.android;

RNFS.downloadFile({
  fromUrl: url,
  toFile: path,
}).promise.then(() => {
  android.actionViewIntent(path, mimeType)
    .then((success) => {
      console.log('success: ', success)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err:', err)
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you sure ```android.actionViewIntent(res.path(), mimeType)``` works with image file? I tried displaying an png <Image> with source uri = res.path(), it works. But with ```android.actionViewIntent(res.path(), 'image/png')```, it displays "Cannot generate thumbnail" in Gallery app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently your device doesn't have other file viewer applications installed such as Polaris office or Office suite or any other of those kind file viewers.

Typically this is the exception you get for this kind of issues. You can either show a warning/toast or show some links to download these apps from play store.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much! I went with OfficeSuite. I will probably end up showing an alert when an error is thrown letting them know they need to download an appropriate viewer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @albeee @Nader After fetching image from an url, do I need to store it into external storage or something? Coz I saw that Nader's code uses ```RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath``` for Android.

Comment: Finally passed it by setting path as ```RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath``` for Android and ```RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath``` for iOS. Leaving it by default causes something like "no such file" message in browser app.

Comment: what is that RNFS for android programatically approach ?

Answer (score -2):

I had this and it's a way to solve it.

```
  try{
    startActivity(intent);
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Error showing pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```